# Is there a logic that allows the display of an image when available in container in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-container

[image: image 1]

Is it possible to create a logic that allows the container to only display only text (image above) or text and image (image below) when image is available.

[image: image 2]

Comment: You can check which condition is true and display what you want on each condition. The easiest way is with (if else). But be careful to manipulate the state the right way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say `person` is an object that has a `name` and optionally an `image`. Then this is a way to write it

```
Column(
  children: [
    Text(person.name),
    if (person.image != null) Image.network(person.image!)
  ],
)
```